# Print Drupal admin links in blocks broken out by sections

Tags: drupal

The Drupal's main admin page contains many links grouped by different purposes.

By default there are following sections: Content management, Site building, Site configuration, User management, Reports

Now I'm using Rootcandy admin theme and want to move all these annoying links into sliding panel which is collapsed by default.

So the question is:

how to split all these links by blocks? I'd like to get "Content management", "Site building", "Site configuration", "User management", "Reports" blocks contaning all related links.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Menu block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block) module. Once enabled, go to the Block Administration page. For each block you want to create, click the *Add menu block* tab. Most of the default options will suit your use case: just set the *Parent Item -> Menu* to *Navigation* and *Parent Item -> Item* to the menu you want to create.